# Read property of annotation

Tags: java, jsp, reflection, annotations, jstl

If I had defined this class:

```
@MainForm(grupo = 3, icone = "user")
public class Usuario {
    ...
}
```

and pass to the view this List (which include the class above):

```
public List<Class<?>> lista_classes_projeto() {
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to read the value for `icone` in this jsp code:

```
        <c:forEach var="option" items="${lista}">
            <li>
                <c:url value="/${option.simpleName}/listagem" var="url"/>
                <a class="link" href="${url}">
                    <i class="icon-"></i>
                    <span>${option.simpleName}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test, but you could give this line a try: (in your for each)

```
((MainForm) option.getAnnotation(MainForm.class)).icone();
```

Note that null handling was ignored. I assume that all `option (class)` has annotation `@MainForm`

Comment: don't work in the jsp page. and yes, all `option (class)` have the annotation `MainForm`

Comment: I can't even build the application. I get an "MainForm can't be resolved to a type". This works if I use in any place of my java code, but don't work in the jsp/jstl code.

Comment: tried class name with package? is the annotation class in your web-app's classpath?

Comment: what does `option.getAnnotations()` return? if it's in your classpth, `MainForm can't be resolved to a type` shouldn't happen... I don't have jsp/jstl env to test. sorry..

Comment: nothing is returned. seems like the List I sent to view is empty.

Comment: @KleberMota then fix that problem first.

Comment: I fix the problem now, but the error continues. Do I need use `<% %>`? If so, how I use the option variable inside this block?